# Android: resources from referenced library project hide resources of client application

Tags: android, openframeworks

I have two Android projects:

**Project A**: a library project (the AndroidLib project of openframeworks).

**Project B:** android project that references **Project A**.

The problem is that when I add a string resource, layout or any type of resources in **Project B**, I cannot access it from the code, instead I can access the resources defined in Project A.

I cleaned the projects and made sure that I access the **R class** with package name of **Project B** and still can't see the resources of **Project B**.

what can be wring here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got it

I just fixed the project by right clicking on the project-> Android Tools->Fix Project Properties